# Difference between Simultaneous and Concurrent users

Tags: performance-testing

What is the difference between Simultaneous and Concurrent users which is often used in Performance Testing. I see the explanations are contradictory in the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably they have the same meaning. In performance testing there should be only one term: **virtual user** which must represent **real user**, that's it. Well-behaved load test has to represent real user as close as possible, otherwise it will not make a lot of sense to run such a test. By "as close as possible" I mean all real user's stuff, i.e.:

- [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)
- [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)
- [Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching)
- Handling embedded resources (images, scripts, styles, fonts included into HTML page)
- Handling [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) requests
- Think time between operations (users don't hammer server non-stop, they need some time to "think" between operations)
- Load test steps (i.e. open login page, perform login, navigate somewhere, etc.)

Given certain virtual users **concurrency** some of the "load test steps" can be (and given more or less high load will be) simultaneous. Also assuming embedded resources and AJAX requests even single HTTP GET request might cause multiple server hits and [the relationship between virtual users and server hits per second](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-relationship-between-users-and-hits-second) is something much more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

simultaneous = same action, same time.  "Everyone push the enter button in 3, 2, 1, Now!"  In Microfocus LoadRunner this is represented by a concept called rendezvous.

Concurrent = operating in same window of time, but each on an independent set of actions.